# Celery worker receives task from Flask view, but never processes them

Tags: python, flask, celery

E: **FOR POSTERITY** Changing to RabbitMQ as a broker works normally. SQLite is not the way to go.

I'm running a Flask application where this function `uploadFile` in `function.py` calls a celery task in `task.py`.

```
## backend/views/function.py
@cgm_blueprint.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
@jwt_required()
@check_read_only_account
def uploadFile():
    
    task = sayHello.delay()
    return jsonify(name=current_app.name, status='Task is running', taskid=task.id), 202
```

```
## backend/celery/task.py
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery, shared_task


def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery('celery', backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'], broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'sqla+sqlite:///var/db/celerydb.sqlite',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+sqlite:///var/db/results.sqlite'
)
celery = make_celery(app)


@celery.task()
def sayHello():
    return 'Hello'
```

I run the celery worker with this command.

`celery -A backend.celery.task.celery worker -Q celery -E --loglevel=DEBUG --concurrency 1 -P solo`

Which returns the following output in the terminal:

```
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,227: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Building graph...
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,227: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: New boot order: {Timer, Hub, Pool, Autoscaler, StateDB, Beat, Consumer}
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,235: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Preparing bootsteps.
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,235: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Building graph...
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,274: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: New boot order: {Connection, Agent, Events, Mingle, Tasks, Control, Gossip, Heart, event loop}
 
 -------------- celery@vagrant v4.4.7 (cliffs)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.4.0-58-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-20.04-focal 2021-05-06 16:09:51
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         celery:0x7faac5d14d10
- ** ---------- .> transport:   sqla+sqlite:///var/db/celerydb.sqlite
- ** ---------- .> results:     sqlite:///var/db/results.sqlite
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (solo)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: ON
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . backend.celery.task.add_together
  . backend.celery.task.sayHello
  . celery.accumulate
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap

[2021-05-06 16:09:51,294: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,294: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,294: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Consumer
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,294: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,310: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to sqla+sqlite:///var/db/celerydb.sqlite
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,311: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,311: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Events
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,316: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,316: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Tasks
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,986: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,986: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Heart
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,986: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,986: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting event loop
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,987: INFO/MainProcess] celery@vagrant ready.
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,987: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->4
```

I'm using SQlite as the broker and backend, and when I query the `celerydb` table, I can see that each call from the API is saved to the `kombu_message` table, but the worker never shows the task as being received.

This is the entry in the table:

```
53|1||{"body": "W1tdLCB7fSwgeyJjaG9yZCI6IG51bGwsICJjYWxsYmFja3MiOiBudWxsLCAiZXJyYmFja3MiOiBudWxsLCAiY2hhaW4iOiBudWxsfV0=", "headers": {"origin": "gen13659@vagrant", "root_id": "a39a00a8-fa71-4477-8905-10f89275df81", "expires": null, "shadow": null, "id": "a39a00a8-fa71-4477-8905-10f89275df81", "kwargsrepr": "{}", "lang": "py", "retries": 0, "task": "backend.celery.task.sayHello", "group": null, "parent_id": null, "group_index": null, "timelimit": [null, null], "argsrepr": "()", "eta": null}, "content-type": "application/json", "properties": {"priority": 0, "body_encoding": "base64", "correlation_id": "a39a00a8-fa71-4477-8905-10f89275df81", "reply_to": "54101d12-6f66-37ad-afbb-5007802d8368", "delivery_info": {"routing_key": "celery", "exchange": ""}, "delivery_mode": 2, "delivery_tag": "c1e17730-4d83-474a-a8a3-a198d4f3702a"}, "content-encoding": "utf-8"}|1|1
```

If I spin up a python shell and run:

```
>>> import backend.celery.task
>>> task = backend.celery.task.sayHello.delay()
>>> print(task.state)
SUCCESS
```

I can see in the worker :

```
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,225: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Preparing bootsteps.
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,227: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Building graph...
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,227: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: New boot order: {Timer, Hub, Pool, Autoscaler, StateDB, Beat, Consumer}
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,235: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Preparing bootsteps.
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,235: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Building graph...
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,274: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: New boot order: {Connection, Agent, Events, Mingle, Tasks, Control, Gossip, Heart, event loop}
 
 -------------- celery@vagrant v4.4.7 (cliffs)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.4.0-58-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-20.04-focal 2021-05-06 16:09:51
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         celery:0x7faac5d14d10
- ** ---------- .> transport:   sqla+sqlite:///var/db/celerydb.sqlite
- ** ---------- .> results:     sqlite:///var/db/results.sqlite
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (solo)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: ON
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . backend.celery.task.add_together
  . backend.celery.task.sayHello
  . celery.accumulate
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap

[2021-05-06 16:09:51,294: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,294: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,294: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Consumer
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,294: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,310: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to sqla+sqlite:///var/db/celerydb.sqlite
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,311: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,311: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Events
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,316: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,316: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Tasks
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,986: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,986: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Heart
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,986: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,986: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting event loop
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,987: INFO/MainProcess] celery@vagrant ready.
[2021-05-06 16:09:51,987: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->4
[2021-05-06 16:24:51,946: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: backend.celery.task.sayHello[e7d4c8ff-352f-462d-bd92-b6d9efaa14e1]  
[2021-05-06 16:24:51,946: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply <function _fast_trace_task at 0x7faac5c55a50> (args:(u'backend.celery.task.sayHello', u'e7d4c8ff-352f-462d-bd92-b6d9efaa14e1', {u'origin': u'gen13385@vagrant', u'lang': u'py', u'task': u'backend.celery.task.sayHello', u'group': None, u'args': [], u'root_id': u'e7d4c8ff-352f-462d-bd92-b6d9efaa14e1', u'delivery_info': {u'priority': 0, u'redelivered': None, u'routing_key': u'celery', u'exchange': u''}, u'expires': None, u'group_index': None, u'correlation_id': u'e7d4c8ff-352f-462d-bd92-b6d9efaa14e1', u'hostname': u'celery@vagrant', u'retries': 0, u'parent_id': None, u'argsrepr': u'()', u'timelimit': [None, None], u'reply_to': u'17ddbaf8-76bc-3f9a-9e1c-5871066fbfd1', u'kwargs': {}, u'eta': None, u'shadow': None, u'id': u'e7d4c8ff-352f-462d-bd92-b6d9efaa14e1', u'kwargsrepr': u'{}'}, '[[], {}, {"chord": null, "callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null}]', u'application/json', u'utf-8') kwargs:{})
[2021-05-06 16:24:51,947: DEBUG/MainProcess] Task accepted: backend.celery.task.sayHello[e7d4c8ff-352f-462d-bd92-b6d9efaa14e1] pid:13571
[2021-05-06 16:24:51,965: INFO/MainProcess] Task backend.celery.task.sayHello[e7d4c8ff-352f-462d-bd92-b6d9efaa14e1] succeeded in 0.0183824979977s: 'Hello'
```

I'm quite a noob and have been stuck on this for a week and none of the SO solutions have worked thus far. I'm required to use these older package versions, unfortunately.

Any ideas why the task is getting stuck in message table but never processed by the worker?

Comment: Did you try to run Celery worker with the default (prefork) concurrency? (Basically: `celery -A backend.celery.task.celery worker -Q celery -E --loglevel=DEBUG --concurrency=1`). SQLite is a terrible choice of broker/result-backend btw...

Comment: Yep, it had the same result as before. I agree on the SQLite, but Redis is not an option. Is RabbitMQ a better choice?